# Adobe Socket Policy File Server Problems

Tags: flash, security, sockets, actionscript, policy

Has anyone been able to successfully implement a service to serve the required socket policy file to FlashPlayer?

I am running the Python implementation of the service provided by Adobe at

```
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html
```

and using the following policy file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
 <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
 <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

and receiving this message from Flash:

```
[SecurityErrorEvent type="securityError" bubbles=false 
cancelable=false eventPhase=2
text="Error #2048: 
Security sandbox violation: http://www.mapopolis.com/family/Tree.swf   
cannot load data from www.mapopolis.com:1900."]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

There's now a module for the Apache webserver to server socket policy files compatible with the new Flash 9.whatever and Flash 10+ which require socket policy files to be served using the Adobe socket protocol.

http://www.beamartyr.net/articles/adobepolicyfileserver.html

Comment: Great to see this apache policy server project, Isaac! Keep up!

Comment: old thread I know. (sorry)  is this project still valid?  I want to use it on an RPi, and AS2.0.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I've hit this a couple of times now, trying to use someone else's policy server, and writing my own.
The elements that I've found that all need to be there:

- listen on socket 843.
- When receiving a new connection, read all data. Don't just send the policy on connect!
- optionally, you can test if the received data is a correct policy request, or just ignore it. I haven't seen a good reason to validate in my usage.
- send the xml with the trailing "\0" byte.
- close the socket!
- more than likely you need the secure="false" option in the allow-access-from section of the policy.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Debian, I've written an Apache module for serving Adobe socket policy files that is available at:

> http://socketpolicyserver.com

The package includes working configuration files in:

> /usr/share/doc/libapache2-mod-socket-policy-server/examples/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using AS3...

You can override crossdomain.xml policy files in your flash like this:

```
Security.allowDomain("*");
Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
```

But if you need crossdomain.xml make sure it is in your root of the server you are trying to access.  Also try a complely base simple version to make sure it works such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Make sure it is named crossdomain.xml and in your root.

You can also change the policy file to another server or filename like this:

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://www.example.com/sub/dir/pf.xml");
```

If you are using AS2/flash8 (first off I am sorry) then you will need to be sure crossdomain.xml is in the root of the server you are hitting.

Comment: I am using the facebooks crossdomain.xml but I keep on getting the error that my checkPolicy is not set :/

Answer (score 1):

your socket server must respond in a special way to the flash socket when this one tries to connect and asks for "crossdomain"

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer9_security_04.html

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer9_security_05.html

Answer (score 1):

Try hosting the policy file at port 843, assuming your admin will allow access to 843.  Here's a link that tells you about socket policy files.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you send a trailing 0-byte after the

```
<cross-domain-policy>
     <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Check the
http://www.lightsphere.com/dev/articles/flash_socket_policy.html